# Enable the Default Ribbon bar when in Runtime Mode

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

MS Access database files can be changed from .accdb or .adp into .accdr.  This is "runtime mode".  When in this runtime mode, the user cannot see the navigation pane (that shows tables and forms and so on)  This is the mode that I am using when I "publish" the database for use by the users.

However, in this mode, the default Ribbon Bar is also hidden.

On the ribbon are some useful things -- like Find, Filter, Export data to Excel and so on.

**How do we turn back on the Ribbon Bar when in runtime mode? (.accdr)**

I know about custom ribbons.  But the idea of creating a whole new ribbon with default items seems daunting.  If that's the only way, is there a pre-fab XML file that I can download from somewhere with the defaults already done?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: No you can not just turn on the standard ribbon bar in runtime. 
As you stated right, you have to build custom ribbons. I have not found anything like a XML for standard ribbons.

But you can use the built-in ribbons from Microsoft in your custom Ribbon. 
You just have to find out the MS-id (as idMSO attribut)

The ribbon for formating text for example is stated in XML

`<group idMso="GroupFontAccess"/>`

I have not found any list with all MS-id's. My tactic is to go to the Options and Ribbons menue, disable the ribbon I want to have and use the export-UI settings-function. Opening the exported file with any XML viewer will show the id (being set visible to false)

It sounds stupid to set all ribbons manually, but think about the fact, that runtime users should not have permanently greyed-out buttons e.g. for Open design view. That is confusing and not very user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Ribbons aren't that hard to create manually. See this [MS Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-Ribbon-45e110b9-531c-46ed-ab3a-4e25bc9413de).

Or you could use a tool to create them for you.

- http://www.accessribbon.de/en/
- http://www.ribboncreator2010.de/en/

Have you thought about saving it as an accde or mde, which stops users from getting access to the code but still allows then functionality, the .accdr method people can just rename and get to everything?

Comment: An accde suggestion is a good one. The only real issue is that the poster may be using the accdr extension to test based on the assumption that end users will have runtime. That being the case, then the poster is right back to requiring some ribbons regardless of using an accdr, or an accde if users only have the free runtime as opposed to full edition of Access.